# Why is there a diference in sign convention for the radius of curvature of spherical mirrors compared to curved refracting surfaces?

Tags: optics, reflection, conventions, curvature, geometric-optics

In the context of spherical mirrors we have

- $R > 0$ for concave mirrors
- $R < 0$ for convex mirrors

But for curved refracting surfaces we have

- $R < 0$ for concave mirrors
- $R > 0$ for convex mirrors

Why is that so?

Comment: this is the convention that makes most sense in my opinion but quite many people use the opposite convention ($R<0$ for concave mirrors ans $R>0$ for convex mirrors). One should bear that in mind and always double check, and best is to always clarify (e.g. using vex and cav as abbreviations)

Answer (score 1):

The general sign rule for the radius of curvature of a spherical surface is the following

> When the center of curvature $C$ is on the same side as the outgoing light, $R> 0$ (the radius of curvature is positive), otherwise $R < 0$

Now in *spherical* **mirrors** we have

- For concave mirrors, $C$ is *always* on the same side as the outgoing light, hence $R > 0$
- For convex mirrors, $C$ is *never* on the same side as the outgoing light, hence $R < 0$

But in general curved **refracting**  surfaces (i.e. not reflecting like mirrors) we have

- For concave mirrors, $C$ is *never* on the same side as the outgoing light, hence $R < 0$
- For convex mirrors, $C$ is *always* on the same side as the outgoing light, hence $R > 0$